# Accepting a string formatted date using Rails and JSON

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, json, date

I'm trying to get a Rails model to accept a date via a JSON message produced by an PHP cURL request. The message is sent to the model's create controller.

The model that I'm passing the message to has a has many relationship with another model (the one that needs the date). I'm want to store the date using a Date object.

The PHP array I'm passing through cURL looks something like this before using json_encode() on the data:

```
$data = array(
    "parent" => array(
        "parent_attr1" => 'blah',
        "childs_attributes" => array(
            array(
                "child_attr1" => 'blabla',
                "child_dateattr => 'mm/dd/yy'
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Should I be formatting the string in "child_dateattr" to be a specific format? Or do I need to  do something in the Rails app to convert the string to a Date object?

Comment: What is implied for `yy`? 18yy, 19yy or 20yy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Date.strptime()`
It works as following:

```
Date.strptime("06/21/81", "%m/%d/%y")
=> Sun, 21 Jun 1981
```

Comment: So in the create controller do something like
@child.child_dateattr = Date.strptime("mm/dd/yy")?

Comment: Yes, that depends on what JSON you get; and how you can extract the string with date for the above operation.